# In Java, how can I load parameters from files?

Tags: java

I want my program to take numerical parameters from a file. My situation is weird, so here's an example:

This hypothetical program will have a database of countries. The user will pick a country. Each country is a folder kept in the same directory as the .class files. In these folders are text files. So if I wanted to get the percentage of Japan's population that is Christian, my program would access the /Japan/religions.txt file, then find the entry that says "Christianity: 12.4%". How can I make it dynamically access files like this? The main thing is I need to get the number for any category of data. Does anyone understand what I'm saying and have the know-how to help me out?

Comment: Are you rigidly tied to this multiple directories construct? It sounds to me like there would be much better ways to store and retrieve data including database or XML.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You should clarify your question to a more specific problem.

Comment: I can use any type of construct, I just figured it would be easiest to do it this way. I don't have any experience with XML. Whatever is best I will do.

Comment: Do you mean if you change some data from text files, the database should be updated automatically?

Comment: `"I just figured it would be easiest to do it this way."` -- I was afraid that your question was in fact an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), and I'm right. No, it's not the best or easiest way to do this. If you have a large amount of data, or the data can grow or change significantly, use a database. If it is relatively small, or you need to send the data as text, then use XML. JAXB could be a nice way to mesh an XML file with your Java classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways this can be done, but the way i like to do is to read in a xml file and store all the data from that file into ArrayList or Vector.

First you would need to create the Religions class with setters a getters of all the data you want to store in. The next step is create a ArrayList/Vector of your Religions class and define the Religions as a object like This:

```
private Religions religions = new Religions();
private ArrayList<Religions> religionsFile = new ArrayList<Religions>();
```

An then create a method of some sort to read in and store the data. I recommend using [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) for reading in the xml files. To store the data you can do something like this:

```
religions.setName("Name Goes Here");
religions.setPopulation(Population Goes Here);
religionsFile.add(religions);
```

Of cause this is just a example of what you can do and the way i would go about doing it. Here are is the [JDOM Ducmentation](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/index.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: JDOM... Well that is what i prefer to use, when reading in xml files.

Comment: Have you used JAXB much?

Comment: No i haven't is any better than jdom?

Comment: It's better if you want to convert XML directly to Java objects (including complex objects that contain other fields, including collection fields such as array lists) and back again. It's truly a thing of beauty, I think much more powerful than JDOM. You should give it a serious look.

Comment: I most definitely will, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need something that is little bit like the method injection that TestNG has, where you can define a DataProvider which provides parameters to Test methods in test classes.  If you re-define your project as a test project, then you can use TestNG  and also use "Apache MetaModel" to read your .csv files.   Of course, you will need a basic understanding of Maven to make that work.   There are a lot of examples of this kind of thing within the realm of "Selenium testing" if you search around on the internet.

Comment: Parameterization within the context of a unit test is a perfectly acceptable way of solving this issue.  In fact, its very common for people do exactly what is suggested by the question in a unit test or functional test.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1. Put that stuff in to a database.
2. Read documentation for [properties and subclasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)